# Calculating the differences between rows in a groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the distance between markers for two roads. My data is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame()

data['dist'] = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
data['road'] = ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B',]
```

I am looking to determine the distance between each marker for each road. I have been using:

```
data['len'] = data['dist'] - data['dist'].shift(1)
```

This, of course, creates an incorrect length when we cross from road A into road B. I have been trying to use a groupby statement, grouping on 'road', but I am not sure how to apply the two functions in one statement without using for loops.

Any help would be amazing.

Jo

Comment: `data.groupby('road')['dist'].diff()`? Seems like a duplicate.

Comment: hahaha... So simple!!! I thought mine was different as it was based on a groupby. Thanks ayhan.